# tree query parameter in jenkins json returns 400 error

Tags: jenkins, tree, http-status-code-400

trying to fetch list of jobs from Jenkins that has 3 level folder structure, with 
myhostname.com.au/jenkins/api/json?tree=jobs[_class,name,buildable]
and getting 400 Bad Request as a response.

None of queries with "tree" work, however others do

i.e.
myhostname.com.au/jenkins/api/json?depth=3&pretty returns all data as expected

same as
myhostname.com.au/jenkins/api/json

couldn't find anything why "tree" wouldn't work.
please advise if you experienced similar,

thansk,

Answer (score 1):

You might need to quote the URL and escape the square brackets as in:

```
curl -k "http://myhostname.com.au/jenkins/nom/api/json?tree=jobs\[_class,name,buildable\]"
```

or without the quotes:

```
curl -k http://myhostname.com.au/jenkins/nom/api/json?tree=jobs\\[_class,name,buildable\\]
```

Comment: thanks for reply! it didn't help, but helped to move it forward - i've found another suggestion how to escape brackets by jenkins/api/json?tree=jobs%5B_class,name,buildable%5D - it didn't return the results expected, but at least no error, continuing to dig with 'depth' parameter